# sudo rootsh on AIX 7

Tags: shell, aix

I'm allowed to use

**"sudo /usr/bin/rootsh   -i -u user_X"**

but furthermore I want to do something like:

**echo 'date' | sudo /usr/bin/rootsh   -i -u  user_X**

Here I get the following answer:

**no tty/pty on stdin: Not a typewriter**

Any ideas how to solve my question?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: tried `sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u user_X "echo date"` ? But it will at most print `date`

Comment: This is not a programming question. I suggest you delete it and repost to [unix.se].

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what actually was granted to your user.

If the command "/usr/bin/rootsh" was granted without any arguments, then you may use `sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u user_X "date"` to execute the `date` command as root.

If the command "/usr/bin/rootsh -u -u user_X" was granted with all these arguments (and no other form, other list of arguments), then you may not launch any other commands because additional arguments are not be allowed.

You can use "sudo -l" to display what exactly you are allowed to execute and which form of the "rootsh" command exists. If you update the question with output of "sudo -l" then it might be possible to provide a more detailed answer.